Escapar caracteres especiales
Tengo un formulario de registro con varios campos para recoger datos.
necesito validar el campo nombre en el que se acepten nombres que incluyan apóstrofes. Si escribo O'Hara, la base de datos no recoge a esa persona. Me han recomendado que aplique addslashes para escapar ese caracter especial, pero no sé cómo se usa, qué códiog debo incluir ni dónde, para que la base de datos recoja datos al ser enviados cuando hay nombres con apóstrofe. Los nombres sin apostrofe los recoge sin proeblemas.
¿Cómo uso  addslashes() para escapar de caracteres como la apóstrofe en un campo de formulario para que la base de datos recoja la info de nombres que llevan apóstrofes?
Soy nueva, no sé utilizarlo ni sé dónde se coloca ni de qué manera.
    <?php 



  @extract($_POST);
  $timestamp=time();
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `xxxxxxxxxxxxxx` ( `Code` , `timestamp` , `FirstName` , `Surname` , `Email` , `Company` , `Address` , `City` , `State` , `Zip` , `Phone` , `Website` , `EmergencyCon` , `EmergConPhone` , `RoomReg` , `DietryName` , `SpecialNeeds` , `PassportName` , `PrefAirport` , `DOB` , `Nickname` , `Consent` , `SharingConsent` , `Bio`) VALUES  ( '', '$timestamp', '$FirstName', '$Surname', '$Email', '$Company', '$Address', '$City', '$State', '$Zip', '$Phone', '$Website', '$EmergencyCon', '$EmergConPhone', '$RoomReg', '$DietryName', '$SpecialNeeds', '$PassportName', '$PrefAirport', '$DOB', '$Nickname', '$Consent', '$SharingConsent', '$Bio')";  
  $valor = mysqli_query ($link, $sql);



  $remove[] = "'";
  $remove[] = '"';
  $remove[] = "-";


  // Redirect
  $redirectURL='submit_confirmation.html';
  header("location:  $redirectURL");
?>


Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Creo que he sido muy clara y honesta. No sé cómo aplicar las sugerencias que apuntas

Las aplicaciones web tienen dos lados. El del cliente que es donde está el formulario, el código HTML, Javascript, y el del servidor (PHP u otro) donde recibes los datos del cliente y harías la inserción en la base de datos. El problema que planteas aquí debes resolver del lado del servidor (PHP) y debes tener en cuenta aspectos tan importantes como la seguridad, ya que clientes mal intencionados puedes manipular los datos y atacar al servidor (es lo que se conoce como Inyección SQL).

En la pregunta anterior te recomendé que usaras consultas preparadas, de modo que el código no sólo funcione, sino que sea seguro. Eso debes hacerlo en el código PHP donde recibes los datos del formulario e intentas hacer la inserción en la base de datos. Es una operación normal y corriente cuando se trabaja en el servidor con datos provenientes de un cliente (el formulario en este caso), pero sin ver el código nada podemos hacer. Pulsa en [edit] y agrega el código PHP para que podamos ayudarte.

Espero haber puesto el código de manera correcta, si no os pido disculpas a todos

@Raquel, no te saldría mejor aprender Cómo hacer un CRUD desde cero?? Porque es difícil explicarte algo de lo cual se ve que no tienes ni idea. Hagamos algo, haz un curso (el que quieras) y luego te podemos ayudar con algún problema en especifico. Yo podría hacer ahora mismo un ejemplo para ti, pero es que no vas a entender la base del CRUD. Que dices??

Justo antes de la linea de la consulta $sql= agrega esta linea: $FirstName =  addslashes($FirstName); y de ese modo estarás escapando los apostrofes para esa variable y podras ingresarlo en la base de datos sin ningún otro cambio. Y si tienes más campos con el mismo problema pues lo mismo, por ejemplo $Surname = addslashes($Surname);.  La respuesta de A.Cedano también sirve y es más segura, claro, pero implican muchos más cambios.

Gracias de todo corazón @masterguru Esto me salva de momento la vida <3

La forma más segura de escapar comillas y carácteres especiales es usando consultas preparadas, las cuales además blindarán tu código contra ataques de Inyección SQL.
Para escribir una consulta preparada en mysqli sólo tienes que poner marcadores ? donde irían los valores, y luego pasar los valores aparte usando el método bind_param.
Por ejemplo:
@extract($_POST);
$timestamp=time();

/*
   bind_param requiere variables, por eso
   definimos $code como un valor en blanco
*/
$code='';

/*
    Consulta preparada, 
    cambiando los valores por marcadores ?
*/

$sql = "INSERT INTO `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` ( `Code` , `timestamp` , `FirstName` , `Surname` , `Email` , `Company` , `Address` , `City` , `State` , `Zip` , `Phone` , `Website` , `EmergencyCon` , `EmergConPhone` , `RoomReg` , `DietryName` , `SpecialNeeds` , `PassportName` , `PrefAirport` , `DOB` , `Nickname` , `Consent` , `SharingConsent` , `Bio`) VALUES     (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $link->prepare($sql);

/*
    Pasamos cada valor respectivo 
    Aquí bind_param hará las sustituciones de forma segura
    permitiendo insertar valores con comilla simple
*/

$stmt->bind_param("ssssssssssssssssssssssss", $code, $timestamp, $FirstName, $Surname, $Email, $Company, $Address, $City, $State, $Zip, $Phone, $Website, $EmergencyCon, $EmergConPhone, $RoomReg, $DietryName, $SpecialNeeds, $PassportName, $PrefAirport, $DOB, $Nickname, $Consent, $SharingConsent, $Bio);

/*
    Ejecutamos, para que la inserción ocurra
    Quizá conviene devolver la cantidad de filas afectadas
    o el ID, en caso de que esta tabla tenga una columna AUTOINCREMENT
*/

$valor=$stmt->execute(); 

Finalmente, e insistiendo en el tema de la seguridad, deberías evitar esta práctica:
@extract($_POST);

El uso de extract() es inseguro, ver por ejemplo aquí y aquí.
Así mismo, silenciar los errores con @ se considera una mala práctica.
Mejor, define tus variables directamente, no importa que sean 24, eso te permitirá hacer controles adicionales, como llevar el código por otro camino cuando se pasen valores en blanco o nulos para columnas que no deben admitir datos con esas características.

Gracias por tu paciencia y explicación, @a-cedano.

@ochoa claro que no tengo ni idea, estoy aprendiendo y por eso estoy aquí preguntando, para aprender. gracias por recordarme que no tengo ni idea. Muchas gracias.

@Raquel en primer lugar, esta es la respuesta que muy amablemente A. Cedano te hizo, mi comentario no está acá. Segundo, este no es el sitio ideal "para aprender", acá se resuelven dudas puntuales, pero explicarte un tema extenso es muy complicado. Tercero, veo que te falta mucho por aprender, y no hablo de programación ya que solo te di un consejo, si lo quieres lo tomas y sino no, pero responder de esa forma solo te da a conocer. Parece que eres arrogante, (ahora que estas aprendiendo) no me imagino en el futuro cuando ya seas toda una desarrolladora. Suerte!

@ochoa De arrogante nada... todo lo contrario. Porque vi que aquí podrían ayudarme a solucionar este problema, pregunté. Llevo una semana con esto... estoy aprendiendo y hay mucho que no entiendo y tengo este fuego por apagar que no sé ni cómo cogerlo. No creo que sea muy difícil ayudar, no solo echar en cara que una no sabe... como dije, lo que tengo muy claro es que no sé. Perdón por pedir ayuda. Gracias por la paciencia.

@a-cedano muchas gracias de nuevo!! <3

Una disculpa mutua y todo resuelto. Venga chicos, no hagáis otro incendio por esto :) . Y, persiste la duda de si el problema del código se resolvió o no ¿? Si es así, Raquel, considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada. Sería bueno que te tomes un tiempo para hacer el recorrido y saber cómo funciona el sitio.

@Raquel Efectivamente en este sitio podrás aprender y te ayudarán a resolver tus dudas, siempre y cuando tus preguntas estén bien formadas (como la de ahora). Te animo a que sigas participando y recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada. Saludo
